# How do I release with BitBucket+Git+Maven

Tags: git, maven, bitbucket, maven-release-plugin

I have specified the following SCM tags in my pom.
However when I do a maven `release:prepare` the tag created has a version 1.0-SNAPSHOT instead of 1.0

Any ideas?

```xml
 <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://<username>@bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo>.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://<username>@bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo>.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<project></url>
</scm>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Ideally you would use SSH to authenticate when doing the release. In that case you would use the following configuration:

```xml
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo>.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo>.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://bitbucket.org/<username>/<repo>.git</url>
</scm>
```

You can also take a look at this [example](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/stash-auto-unapprove-plugin/src/29d64c8077f0495be7fb5c19c8afdc3a6f6f005c/pom.xml?at=master).

Comment: Thanks for this Jens, it helped me! However please note there's a typo in the above "connection" tag; there should only be one slash after bitbucket.org. The POM to which you linked has the correct format.

Comment: link to the example is broken

Comment: The xml looks malformed and it doesn't let me edit it.

Comment: @cahen, @ Ramin : <username> and <repo> are placeholders. You should replace them with the the corresponding values!

Comment: I meant the link to the example, not the URL in the XML